# Basic table structure

Tags: html, html-table

Display table with `600px` width having three rows. First row should have full width. second row with two td having 50% width each and third row with three td with equal length.

What I have done so far:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <p>Hey I am first row</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <p>Hey I am second row</p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <p>Hey I am second row</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="33.33%">
            <p>Hey I am third row</p>
        </td>
        <td width="33.33%">
            <p>Hey I am third row</p>
        </td>
        <td width="33.33%">
            <p>Hey I am third row</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to get rid of the nested table? Then [edit] your question and specify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is tricky... You need to keep 6 as your base and work on it, so that you **don't** need to use nested tables. May be you can do like this:

```css
table {width: 600px; text-align: center;}
table td {border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Full Width</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&frac12;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&frac12;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&#8531;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&#8531;</td>
    <td colspan="2">&#8531;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps?